# implication of perfect tense

Tags: tense

> Harry had the best morning ***he'd had in a long time***. (Harry
>   Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

The prefect tense above makes a range of which the best is selected out. So, in fact, *he’d had in long time* means ‘during a long period of time.’ Is this right understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly. If we rewrite the sentence in a different way, it might be clearer:

> It had been a long time since Harry'd had a morning this good.

In this case *in a long time* essentially means exactly that; it has been a long time since [x] last happened. (That is, *a lot of time has passed since [x] last happened*.) In this case, it has been a long time since Harry had a morning as good as this one.